# How do I report a bug in the Bitcoin client application?

Tags: client

I just installed the v0.4 client and have a bug to report... where can I do this?

If you could also describe how to check if the bug has been reported already, that would be great too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the issues page on github. https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues?state=open

You can also search through the issues to see if yours is already reported.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the github issue tracker, if you're a fan of real-time communication, you could also try dropping by the #bitcoin-dev IRC channel on freenode and chatting to the folks on there about your issue.