# When I have a problem running the bitcoin client, where can I go to get help?

Tags: bitcoin-core

Let's assume that either a [bug report](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/1301/how-do-i-report-a-bug-in-the-bitcoin-client-application) exists already, or the problem is unlikely to be caused by a bug.

What I know so far is:

1. This site will be appropriate for some support questions, and the mechanism for the site encourages peer review of each answer. [Here's an example](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/3487/99-done-for-over-1-hour) of a support question.
2. The [bitcointalk forums](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?board=4.0) have a technical support category that is likely to give a good response as there are lots of active users.

Where else might I get timely support? (paid or unpaid)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have mentioned them all:

bitcointalk,

bitcoin.stackexchange,

github issues page,

bitcoin-dev.

For commercial companies offering bitcoin client support see Stephen Gornick's answer.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a problem such as a bug that might affect other users, the community wants to know, find the root cause, and document or fix the behavior.

If it is a feature request or suggestion for improvement, there are processes for those as well.  e.g., BIP submissions.

There is help from professional service organizations that offer their services as well.

- http://www.BitcoinConsultancy.com
- http://helpcoin.com/contact.html